# WebMethod not being called. ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I followed a very simple example of autocompletion using ajax and cannot get mine to work. I stepped threw the code and it looks like it never goes to my webmethod. What else is there to check?

**.aspx**

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">

    </asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtFrom" runat="server">
</asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtFrom" MinimumPrefixLength="1" ServiceMethod="GetSuggestions">
</ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

**.aspx.cs**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
public static string[] GetSuggestions(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
{
    string[] members = { "Nick", "John", "Bob" };

    return (from m in members where m.StartsWith(prefixText, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) select m).Take(count).ToArray();
}
```

I created a webservice to use instead of putting my method directly in the class, but I get the same result.

Comment: Is your web method static? It can only be static if it's within a page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static string[] GetSuggestions(string prefixText, int count, string contxtKey)
```

You wrote **contxtKey** instead of **contextKey**

Remember, the signature (type, parameters name, return type) [has to match exactly](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/autocomplete/autocomplete.aspx).

> If the context key is used, it should
>   have the same signature with an
>   additional parameter named contextKey
>   of type string:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
public string[] GetCompletionList(
    string prefixText, int count, string contextKey) { ... }
```

> Note that you can replace
>   "GetCompletionList" with a name of
>   your choice, but the return type and
>   parameter name and type must exactly
>   match, including case.

Comment: Ok, I changed it to contextKey, but it still doesn't call it/work. Shouldn't it at least jump to the method during stepping through it?

Comment: Ok, I just removed the whole string contextKey and it now works. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, the function including "string contextKey" should work if you add both "UseContextKey" and "ContextKey" attributes to the AutoCompleteExtender control.

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear that your scriptmanager is configured to allow for page methods, but that your "GetSuggestions" is a page method (on an .aspx.cs) rather than a service call (on an .asmx).

Try editing the script manager to look like:

```
<asp:ScriptManager
ID=”scriptManager”
EnablePageMethods=”true”
runat=”server” >
```

If you want to move your method call to an .asmx then your AutoCompleteExtender should be modified to reference the .asmx file like this:

```
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtFrom" MinimumPrefixLength="1" ServiceMethod="GetSuggestions" ServicePath="AutoCompleteService.asmx">
                    </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

I think you just tried to blend the two techniques and ended up just little bit off.